# Getting main activity context

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am currently working on an Android project where there are 7 classes: MainActivity, FragmentPagerAdapter, FragmentOne, FragmentTwo, RecyclerViewAdapter, Webview Fragment and an Object class.

The object class (News) stores image names, titles, URLs and dates.

FragmentOne and FragmentTwo are TabItems for a TabLayout and they are categories for the News, and it is being handled by the FragmentPagerAdapter.

The `CardView` is used to populate both Fragments using a RecyclerViewAdapter.

But the problem is, in the RecyclerViewAdapter, I couldn't get the image to show in the cardview using:

`getResources.getIdentifier(news.get(index).get_ImageName, drawable, mContext. getPackageName());`

I'm guessing because the context that I passed from FragmentOne to the RecyclerViewAdapter is the fragment context and not MainActivity's context?

The following are my codes.

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager vp = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
private String title[]={"Cybersecurity", "AI"};

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new CybersecurityFragment();
        case 1:
            return new AIFragment();
    }
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return title[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}
```

customAdapter:

```
private Context mContext;
private List<News> newsList;

public customAdapter(Context mContext, List<News> newsList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.newsList = newsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    Log.d("Member", "pls1");
    return new MyViewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewholder holder, final int position) {
    holder.titleview.setText(newsList.get(position).getNews_title());
    int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(newsList.get(position).getImageName(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
    Log.d("Member200", newsList.get(position).getImageName());
    Log.d("Member100", String.valueOf(resID));
    Log.d("Member", "pls");
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(resID);
    holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Member", newsList.get(position).getNews_url());
            WebviewFragment fragment = WebviewFragment.newInstance(newsList.get(position).getNews_url());
            AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
            appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cybersecurity_rv, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsList.size();
}

public static class MyViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CardView cardview;
    TextView titleview;
    ImageView imageview;

    public MyViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        titleview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
        imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_image);

    }
}
```

FragmentOne:

```
private String category, news_title, image_name, news_urls;
private Date news_date;
private ArrayList<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<News> cybersecurity_list = new ArrayList<>();


public CybersecurityFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cybersecurity, container, false);
    try{
        final InputStream txtFile =getActivity().getAssets().open("news_items.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(txtFile));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line!=null){
            int colonIndex = line.indexOf(":");
            if (line.contains("category")){
                category = line.substring(colonIndex+1);
            }
            else if (line.contains("photo")) {
                image_name = line.substring(colonIndex+1);
            }
            else if (line.contains("title"))
            {
                news_title = line.substring(colonIndex+1);
            }
            else if (line.contains("website"))
            {
                news_urls = line.substring(colonIndex+1);
            }
            else if (line.contains("date"))
            {
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                news_date = format.parse(line.substring(colonIndex+1));
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (category != null && image_name != null && news_title != null && news_urls != null && news_date != null){
                newsList.add(new News(category, image_name, news_title, news_urls, news_date));
                category = null;
                image_name = null;
                news_title = null;
                news_urls = null;
                news_date = null;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (News n : newsList){
        if(n.getCategory().contains("cyber")) {
            cybersecurity_list.add(new News(n.getCategory(), n.getImageName(), n.getNews_title(), n.getNews_url(), n.getNews_date()));
            Log.d("Member", n.getImageName());
        } else {
            Log.d("Member", "no");
        }
    }

    RecyclerView rv_cs = view.findViewById(R.id.cybersecurity_rv);
    customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(getContext(), cybersecurity_list);
    rv_cs.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    rv_cs.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Please advise on how to fix this. Thank you all!

Comment: Since every View has a Context, you can always get a valid Context for calling getResources() or getPackageName() from the ViewHolder: holder.getItemView().getContext() So there's no need to pass a Context into the Adapter. But maybe the Context is not the issue here. Try using some simple drawable resource id for the ImageView (something starting with R.drawable.  ). If this does work then you know the problem is with how you build your drawable resource identifiers

Comment: in CybersecurityFragment Log.d("Member", n.getImageName()); are you getting valid image names??

Comment: @PavanNagaraja yes I am getting valid image names.

Answer (score 0):

write a Uitlity.java class

```
public static Drawable getDrawableFromName(Context context,String name){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

```
holder.imageview.setImageDrawable(Utility.getDrawableFromName(mContext,code));
```

This worked for me

Comment: I'm still getting 0 from the resourceId. Could it be due to the defType "drawable" ?

Comment: @arandomprogrammer can I check your Log especially Log.d("Member", n.getImageName()); image names should be lower case no numbers are allowed and no spaces in the names.